# Python win32api.mouse_event TypeError

Tags: python, winapi, pyhook, pythoncom

```
import sys
import win32api, win32con
import pyHook
import pythoncom

def CursorLeft():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -1, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0)

def Quit():
    print "Quitting"
    sys.exit()

# create a keyboard hook
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    print 'MessageName:', event.MessageName
    print 'Key:', event.Key
    if event.Key in ['Numpad2']:
        CursorLeft()
    elif event.Key in ['End']:
        Quit()
    return True

def OnMouseEvent(event):
    print 'Position:', event.Position
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = OnMouseEvent
hm.HookMouse()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

The function CursorLeft works fine every other time.  It also works fine without any negative numbers as parameters.  I am completely lost as to why this is happening!

First call, fine.

Second call,

> TypeError: an integer is required

Third call, fine.

Fourth call,

> TypeError: an integer is required.

so on and so on.

---

### Solved

```
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, -1, 0, 0, 0)
```

The last two parameters passed allow the function to behave properly.  I am still not sure as to why and would **still like to know** but at least **it is working now**.

### Solved

```
return True
```

Very important that the event functions return true.

Comment: Haha thank you so much!  I was dealing with the same problem but my solution was to make two events one for mouse UP and one for DOWN so that one of them will work :P

Comment: @Junkah - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> `return True`
>
> Very important that the event functions return true.

~ answer per [Junkah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904693/junkah)